# Avoiding a ConstraintError when updating objects in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have got a SET function which sets the object into IndexedDB with particular key:

```
_that.set = function(data, key) {
    var transaction = _db.transaction([_tblName], "readwrite"),
        store = transaction.objectStore(_tblName), 
        request = store.add(data, key);

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error", e.target.error.name);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Added to db successfully.");
    };
};
```

I have got an UPDATE function which updates the object in IndexedDB with particular key:

```
_that.update = function(data, key) {

    var transaction = _db.transaction([_tblName], "readwrite"),
        store = transaction.objectStore(_tblName),
        request = store.put(data, key);

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error", e.target.error.name);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Object been updated", key);
    };
};
```

and I have got GET function:

```
_that.get = function(key, callback) {

    if (key === "" || isNaN(key)) {
        return;
    }

    var transaction = _db.transaction([_tblName], "readonly"), 
        store = transaction.objectStore(_tblName), 
        request = store.get(key);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var res = e.target.result;
        callback(key, res);
    };
};
```

I want to create SETORUPDATE function for IndexedDB which will work as SET function, and in case onerror event will call GET function, update data and then call UPDATE function. The error is ConstraintError, which means the object with the respective key already exists in the database. Is there a way to avoid this error comingup in the console, but trigger GET and UPDATE instead? NOTE: Variables with the underscore signs in front are instance variables declared on the top the Class and initialized in the constructor.

UPDATE: I need to change the value of data variable before updating it with the same key only in case the key with some object already exists in the table. That is why it is important to check whether the same key already exists before update. I want something like this:

```
_that.setOrUpdate = function(data, key) {
    var transaction = _db.transaction([_tblName], "readwrite"),
        store = transaction.objectStore(_tblName), 
        request = store.add(data, key);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Added to db successfully.");
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        _that.get(key);
        // make some changes to the data
        _that.update(data, key);
    };
};
```

Comment: It should work in onerror function. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That is already what `IDBObjectStore.put` does.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore.put) It will update an object if the key already exists, and it will add a new object otherwise. So you could just rename your `update` function to `setorupdate` and use that everywhere.

Comment: I need to make some changes to the value of the object before putting it back with the same key.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry, you mentioned it correct, I didn't ask it right.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually figured it out myself. I can use GET method first, and then UPDATE on ONSUCCESS.

```
_that.setOrUpdate = function(newValSerialized, key) {
    var transaction = _db.transaction([_tblName], "readwrite"),
        store = transaction.objectStore(_tblName),
        request = store.get(key);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var oldValSerialized = e.target.result;

        // make changes to data and put it as newVal object.           
        requestUpdate = store.put(newVal, key);

    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.dir(e.target.error.name);
    };
};
```

The idea is GET method never returns ConstraintError. It either finds it or gives undefined. Update method is also going either update or add. Therefore I won't see errors in my console.